# Chrome Extension: multiple extensions acting on the same element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, race-condition

How would Chrome handle this scenario.

Suppose I have two extensions installed. One extension that turns the page blue and the other one that turns the page red. Which extension gets priority?

Comment: You could just try it, you know.

Comment: @Amaan yeah I know. But I thought this would be useful for people searching. I'll try it in a few minutes. But feel free to answer if you get there before me :)

Comment: hmm, appears to run both with the first extension in the chrome://settings/extensions list getting priority.

Comment: @Chamilyan That is wrong: The order of display is not relevant. I've created two demo extensions to verify my statements (source code here: http://pastebin.com/hUNkG8TM). Just toggle between them.

Comment: @RobW good stuff. Thanks for expressing all the different factors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The final behaviour depends on the following factors:

- **[Specifity of the CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Specificity)**. Example: `html body` is more specific than `body`.
- Shorthand properties: `background-color:red;` always overrides `background:cyan;`.
- The existence of the `!important` flag: `!important` declarations can only be overridden by another `!important` declaration.
- **Order of execution**: Extensions which are installed more recently are executed **last**.
  This means that the extension which was (re)loaded in the end will "win", provided that the previous decision rules were undecided.

Comment: PS. The order of execution is also affected by the [`run_at`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration) manifest setting.

Answer (score 3):

Both extensions will execute.  The one that executes first will turn the page to one color, the second to other color.  Last color prevails.

The sequence of execution depends on many things, for example, if both extensions are listening to the same event, the sequence depends on which added its listener first.